# Binded Result in Spring MVC returning null

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have an object that I bind to the view using the `ModelAttribute` named `SurveyDetail`.  In that object I have 2 attributes named `id` and `surveyYear`.  In order to access the values in the `POST` method, I have a hidden field for each attribute.  The surveyYear value is returned properly in the controller but id returns null.  They are both part of surveyDetail and I can't understand why it binds correctly for surveyYear but not for id?  No errors are thrown and on the initial `GET` it has the correct value in the id field, but as soon as it gets to `POST` the id value returns null.  Also, when I do request.getParameter("id")  the correct value is returned but it returns null if I try to reference the binded path `surveyDetail.getId`.  Please help I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  the id field doesn't exist anywhere else on the page, where could the null be coming from?

Controller `Post` Method:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String submit(@ModelAttribute(WebConstants.SURVEY_DETAIL) SurveyDetail surveyDetail, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
{   

    if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled())
        LOGGER.debug(surveyDetail.getId()  + " Year : " + surveyDetail.getSurveyYear());    

    if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled())
        LOGGER.debug("REQUEST PARAMETER: " + request.getParameter("id"));

     return WebConstants.SELECT_STATES_VIEW_REDIRECT; 

}
```

JSP  Form:

```
<sf:form method="POST" name="form1" id="form1" modelAttribute="surveyDetail">  

    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="workTable-full">       

        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">&nbsp;
                <sf:input type="hidden" path="surveyYear" id="year" cssClass="inputbox-survey" maxlength="100" size="10" />             
                <sf:input type="hidden" path="id" id="id" cssClass="inputbox-survey" maxlength="100" size="10" />   
            </td>
        </tr>   

        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><input type="submit" class="small-short inner2" value="Enter Data" alt="Enter Data" title="Enter Data" id="cr8StateTable" name="cr8StateTable"/> <strong>- Click this button to start entering individual State data</strong>
            </td>
        </tr>

   </table>
```

Comment: Use `<sf:hidden />` instead